# Which complete weighted graphs are obtained from finite metric spaces?

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a finite metric space with $X = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$. We can associate to this metric space a complete weighted graph with vertices labelled by the points of $X$, and edges weighted by distance (i.e. the edge joining the vertices $x_i$ and $x_j$ is given the weight $d(x_i, x_j)$). This construction gives an injective map

$$\{\text{finite metric spaces}\} \to \{\text{complete weighted graphs}\}.$$

I would like to know if it there is a way to tell if a given complete weighted graph is in the image of this map. More precisely, I would like to know the answer to the following question.

> Can we characterise those complete weighted graphs which are obtained from finite metric spaces as above?

One necessary condition is that all the weights be positive. With this assumption, the only thing that requires checking is whether the weights satisfy the conditions imposed by the triangle inequality. Is there an efficient way to do this? That is, is there a method other than brute force?